# Extract information from client certificate using ISTIO

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar, servicemesh

I plan to use ISTIO to implement the service mesh and use mTLS between the services.

Some services require some information about the client like CN from it's client certificate.

How can I configure ISTIO to extract the CN from client certificate and insert it into a custom header?

Comment: Can you include more information about your usecase? What did you try already? Do you have any deployment files you can share? This would be useful for further troubleshooting.

Comment: you want to get the CN from the certs used by Istio for mTLS? that should be transparent to your app.

Comment: @suren - yes. how will the APP get that info? SSL Termination occurs in the side car before the service.

Comment: @JeraldBaker you could use [X-Forwarded-Client-Cert Headers](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/network-topologies/#configuring-x-forwarded-client-cert-headers)

Comment: @JeraldBaker any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Use subject parser from istio [doc](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log/usage)

You can add **%DOWNSTREAM_PEER_SUBJECT%** to your service VirtualService:

```
http:
- match:
  - uri:
      prefix: ###
  route:
  - destination:
      host: # service name
      port:
        number: # service port
    headers:
      request:
        set:
          X-CLIENT-SSL-CN: "%DOWNSTREAM_PEER_SUBJECT%"
```

And then have it in your request headers in 'X-Client-Ssl-Cn'